# Automate data preprocessing on AWS sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, etl, amazon-sagemaker

Is there a way to Automate the data preprocessing on Sagemaker on weekly basis 
the preprocessing can include many simple transformations over the data in MBs from S3.

My Idea of Automation is like Triggering a script or a notebook instance that could run weekly

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using Lambda + CloudWatch Event/Rule?
You can write a lambda function which creates a SageMaker job and create a CloudWatch Event rule to trigger it once a week. Therefore, you don't need to have a notebook instance running 24 hours every day.

Here is an example - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html

Hope this helps!